# Scroll to closest div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the issue I am having is getting my script to work correctly where it would scroll up to the closest div with the class '.orangered' on click of the 'scrollBtn'. What I want to be able to do is if there are multiple instances then it will scroll to the one closest to the button, if there is only one instance then it'll just scroll to that one.

I've tried using different instances of .closest to no avail.

Can anyone shed any light?

Cheers.

p.s Excuse the legacy code I'm dealing with, I've included a CodePen here because of that!

CodePen: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/mgZJQJ

```js
$(".product-availability-list").has("span:contains('This quantity of items is currently not available.')").parents('.cart-row').addClass('orangered');

$(".scrollBtn").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.orangered').offset().top - 10
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.orangered { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart-row">
    <div class="cart-cell item-image">
        <picture>
            <img itemprop="image">
        </picture>
    </div>
 
 <div class="cart-cell item-total">
  <div class="product-extras">
   <div class="product-extra is-mobile item-quantity-details">
    <div class="product-availability-list">
     <span class="not-available-quantity js-cart-product-error" style="display: none;">
      This quantity of items is currently not available.
     </span>
                
     <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
      <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
     </div>
     
     <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
      <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="cart-cell item-quantity-details is-mobile">
  <div class="product-availability-list">
   <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
    <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
   </div>
         
   <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
    <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
   </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- /.cart-row -->




<div class="cart-row">
    <div class="cart-cell item-image">
        <picture>
            <img itemprop="image">
        </picture>
    </div>
 
 <div class="cart-cell item-total">
  <div class="product-extras">
   <div class="product-extra is-mobile item-quantity-details">
    <div class="product-availability-list">
     <span class="not-available-quantity js-cart-product-error" style="display: none;">
      This quantity of items is currently not available.
     </span>
                
     <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
      <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
     </div>
     
     <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
      <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="cart-cell item-quantity-details is-mobile">
  <div class="product-availability-list">
   <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
    <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
   </div>
         
   <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
    <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
   </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- /.cart-row -->


<div class="cart-row">
    <div class="cart-cell item-image">
        <picture>
            <img itemprop="image">
        </picture>
    </div>
 
 <div class="cart-cell item-total">
  <div class="product-extras">
   <div class="product-extra is-mobile item-quantity-details">
    <div class="product-availability-list">
     In Stock Item
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="cart-cell item-quantity-details is-mobile">
  <div class="product-availability-list">
   In Stock Item
  </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- /.cart-row -->














<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>

<p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero.</p>

<p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum.</p>


<div class="scrollBtn">
    Scroll Button
</div>
```

Comment: Always worth reading what a method *actually* does when what you think it *might* be doing doesn't seem to be working: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you put the class onto the siblings of the scroll button, to get the closest sibling with the orangered class, you can use `prevAll('.orangered').first()`

This will search for all previous siblings with the class orangered and return you the first one (which is the one closest to the button)

```js
$(".product-availability-list").has("span:contains('This quantity of items is currently not available.')").parents('.cart-row').addClass('orangered');

$(".scrollBtn").click(function() {
  var scrollPosition = $(this).prevAll('.orangered').first().offset().top - 10;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPosition
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.cart-row {
  height: 100vh;
  /* test only */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart-row">
  <div class="cart-cell item-image">
    <picture>
      <img itemprop="image">
    </picture>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-cell item-total">
    <div class="product-extras">
      <div class="product-extra is-mobile item-quantity-details">
        <div class="product-availability-list">
          <span class="not-available-quantity js-cart-product-error" style="display: none;">
      This quantity of items is currently not available.
     </span>

          <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
            <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
          </div>

          <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
            <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-cell item-quantity-details is-mobile">
    <div class="product-availability-list">
      <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
        <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
      </div>

      <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
        <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.cart-row -->




<div class="cart-row">
  <div class="cart-cell item-image">
    <picture>
      <img itemprop="image">
    </picture>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-cell item-total">
    <div class="product-extras">
      <div class="product-extra is-mobile item-quantity-details">
        <div class="product-availability-list">
          <span class="not-available-quantity js-cart-product-error" style="display: none;">
      This quantity of items is currently not available.
     </span>

          <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
            <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
          </div>

          <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
            <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-cell item-quantity-details is-mobile">
    <div class="product-availability-list">
      <div class="jsCartStockMsg jsQtyCartStockMsg jsOosFace">
        <span>THIS QUANTITY OF ITEMS IS <strong>NOT AVAILABLE</strong></span>
      </div>

      <div class="jsCartQtyMsg">
        <span>PLEASE EDIT THE QUANTITY</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.cart-row -->


<div class="cart-row">
  <div class="cart-cell item-image">
    <picture>
      <img itemprop="image">
    </picture>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-cell item-total">
    <div class="product-extras">
      <div class="product-extra is-mobile item-quantity-details">
        <div class="product-availability-list">
          In Stock Item
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cart-cell item-quantity-details is-mobile">
    <div class="product-availability-list">
      In Stock Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.cart-row -->














<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
  elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>

<p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero,
  sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
  tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero.</p>

<p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
  cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris.
  Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum.</p>


<div class="scrollBtn">
  Scroll Button
</div>
```

[More information about `prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

Comment: Perfect! Cheers dude.

Comment: No problems, glad it helped :)